# Hotswapper plugin is not reloading classes in web project

Tags: hotswapagent

Hotswapper plugin is not reloading classes in web project (JSF, maven based) but resource files(xhtml) are reloading smoothly.

Following are my configurations.

```
Server: Wildfly11
Java version : 1.8.0_191
DCEVM Vesion: 25.71-b01-dcevmlight-26
Hot swapper agent : 1.3.1-SNAPSHOT (2019-04-02)
Java Option to start server: -XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:/home/user/HotSwapAgent/hotswap-agent-1.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar=autoHotswap=true -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000"
```

I have added the following attributes in hotswap-agent.properties file of war project

```
LOGGER=trace
extraClasspath=/home/user/HotSwapTest/target/classes
webappDir=/home/user/HotSwapTest/src/main/webapp
watchResources=/home/user/HotSwapTest/target/classes
autoHotswap=true
autoHotswap.port=8000
```

In server startup i'm getting the following message.

```
'org.hotswap.agent.plugin.hotswapper.HotswapperPlugin' initialized in ClassLoader 'ModuleClassLoader for Module
```

Now i'm compiling the java file and the class is updated in the class folder. But the changes are not reloaded in the wildfly server.

How to make reloading of classes? 
Note: Hotswapp is working fine if i'm attching netbeans debugger.